# Creating a new FreeBSD port for an application that uses NPM, not Make

Tags: freebsd, porting

I'm creating a FreeBSD port for an application ([Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/)) that doesn't use Make; instead, it uses NPM:

```
npm run binary-build-linux
cd cli
npm run build
```

There are two options I can see:

1. Add a Makefile to the work directory as a patch.
2. Convince the upstream maintainers to take a Makefile that would be solely used by this port.

I'm wondering if there's a third option I've missed: modify my port's Makefile to run a series of shell commands in lieu of a Makefile?  Having read the porter's handbook I can't see any way of doing that though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use `make` for example, [this is port](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/blob/master/sysutils/immortal/Makefile#L24) is using [go](https://golang.org/) in the `do-build` target: (check the [Additional Build Targets, target-OPT-on and target-OPT-off](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/makefile-options.html):

```
do-build:
    @cd ${WRKSRC}/src/github.com/${GH_ACCOUNT}/${GH_PROJECT}; \
    ${SETENV} ${MAKE_ENV} ${BUILD_ENV} GOPATH=${WRKSRC} go build -ldflags \
    "-s -w -X main.version=${PORTVERSION}" -o immortal cmd/immortal/main.go;
    @cd ${WRKSRC}/src/github.com/${GH_ACCOUNT}/${GH_PROJECT}; \
    ${SETENV} ${MAKE_ENV} ${BUILD_ENV} GOPATH=${WRKSRC} go build -ldflags \
    "-s -w -X main.version=${PORTVERSION}" -o immortalctl cmd/immortalctl/main.go;
    @cd ${WRKSRC}/src/github.com/${GH_ACCOUNT}/${GH_PROJECT}; \
    ${SETENV} ${MAKE_ENV} ${BUILD_ENV} GOPATH=${WRKSRC} go build -ldflags \
    "-s -w -X main.version=${PORTVERSION}" -o immortaldir cmd/immortaldir/main.go;
```

This other [port using `node`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/blob/f6cc85df43c798e128521cfcaf64986d7f299507/net-mgmt/semaphore/Makefile#L61):

```
do-build:
    @(cd ${WRKSRC}/public ; node ./bundler.js )
    @(cd ${WRKSRC} ; go-bindata -o util/bindata.go -pkg util config.json db/migrations/ public/css public/html public/html/projects public/html/projects/repositories public/html/projects/inventory public/html/projects/templates public/html/projects/users public/html/projects/environment public/html/projects/keys public/html/users public/html/auth public/img public/js public/js/services public/js/controllers public/js/controllers/projects public/js/routes public/js/factories public/node_modules public/node_modules/lodash public/node_modules/lodash/fp public/node_modules/async public/node_modules/async/dist public/node_modules/async/internal public/vendor public/vendor/fontawesome public/vendor/fontawesome/less public/vendor/fontawesome/fonts public/vendor/sweetalert public/vendor/moment public/vendor/bootstrap public/vendor/bootstrap/fonts public/vendor/bootstrap/dist public/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css public/vendor/bootstrap/dist/fonts public/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js public/vendor/bootstrap/less public/vendor/bootstrap/less/mixins public/vendor/angular-loading-bar )
    @(cd ${WRKSRC}/cli ; ${SETENV} ${MAKE_ENV} GOPATH=${WRKSRC} go build -o semaphore ./... )
```

Both ports use the `BUILD_DEPENDS` (check the [Dependencies in the porter handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/makefile-depend.html))

```
BUILD_DEPENDS=  ${LOCALBASE}/bin/go:lang/go \
        ${LOCALBASE}/bin/go-bindata:devel/go-bindata \
        npm>=0:www/npm
```